# Jquery - Changing URL used in load()

Tags: php, jquery, load

I'm using the following to auto refresh the contents of a div.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#log").load("test.php?q=" + $('#sq').val());
        var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
     $("#log").load("test.php?q=" + $('#sq').val());
        }, 1000); 

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

This seems to work fine. I have a text field with the name 'sq' and anything entered in there is searched for by test.php.

My page also has 2 other form fields.
A checkbox and another text field. The checkbox has the id 'chk' and the text field 'txt'.

What I would like to do is change the URL being used by load() if the checkbox is ticked and a value is entered in the text field.  Obviously this will also need to include 'sq'.

Can some one point me in the right direction.

The URL with out the check box being ticked is : ( is it is now )

```
test.php?q=VALUE_FROM_sq
```

With the checkbox ticked it needs to be :

```
test.php?s=1&txt=VALUE_FROM_txt&q=VALUE_FROM_sq
```

Then test.php can use $_REQUEST to get the values passed.

My network box only supports php4 so that does limit me some..

Can some one point me in the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add some logic in the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    var refreshId = setInterval(LoadLog, 1000); 
    LoadLog();
});

function LoadLog() {
    var sq = $('#sq').val();
    var text = $("#txt").val();
    var url = "test.php?q=" + encodeURIComponent(sq);
    if ($("#chk").is(":checked") && text.length > 0)
        url += "&s=1&txt=" + encodeURIComponent(text);
    $("#log").load(url);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. Do I need to use encodeURIComponent ? What will I need to do to the test.php page to receive this ?

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` ensures that correct value is passed to the server e.g. even a space might break the URL and should be encoded. The PHP will get it automatically and know to decode it properly you don't need to do anything further.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the URL in a separate variable and update it on the changed event of the checkbox.

```
var url = "test.php?q=VALUE_FROM_sq"

$(document.body).on('change', '#chk', function (event) {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {  
    url = "test.php?s=1&txt=VALUE_FROM_txt&q=VALUE_FROM_sq"
  } else {
    url = "test.php?q=VALUE_FROM_sq"
  }
}
```